# Delete default version of the default module app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to delete the default version of the default module on app engine. When I run:

```
appcfg.py delete_version -A app_id -V version
```

I am getting:

```
Cannot delete the default version of the default module.
```

I do not need anymore this version as I have created a module for my app engine application (with a version inside).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is showing that "Cannot delete default version" on the Admin Console, it seems that this is restricted. So the only way I can think of now is to deploy the newest version to the App Engine, then make the newest one as the default version for your App Engine application. Finally you can delete the previous version on your App Engine.

Comment: At least, is it possible to replace the default version ?

Comment: @user2284570, definitely you can feel free to replace the default version